# Check property of object to have a zero-array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, properties

When I `console.log` `data` from an ajax call I get this log:

```
Object {next_id: null, images: Array[0]}
images: Array[0]
next_id: null
__proto__: Object
```

So my object isn't `0` nor empty. I would like to write an if-statement that runs when `data` (as object) returns the property `images` that has a 0 array.

Something like:

```
if (data:images === [0])
```

In which `data` is the jQuery object and `images` a property of that object.

Comment: `[0]` is the size of the array, not the contents.

Comment: If you're trying to check if `images` is an empty array use `if(data.images.length===0)`. If you are trying to check if it is an array with one element that is the number `0` use `if(data.images.length===1 && data.images[0]===0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
if (data.images.length === 0)
```

You can access methods and properties through `.` symbol. And you can check the array length.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you can try:

```
if (data.images.lenght === 0) {
    // no elements
}
```